# Set port for php artisan.php serve

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, php-5.4

How do we set a custom port for test server?

Normally when we do

```
php artisan serve
```

the folder gets served as :

```
localhost:8000
```

How do could we access one folder as:

```
localhost:8080
```

I want to access two different development sites on my localhost.

Comment: `php artisan serve --help` will show the usage and options. `--help` is available on every artisan command.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

### Laravel 5.8 to 8.0 and above

Simply pass it as a paramter:

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

You may also bind to a specific host by:

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

Or (for Laravel 6+) you can provide defaults by setting SERVER_PORT and SERVER_HOST in your .env file. You might need to do php artisan cache: clear as well. (thanks @mohd-samgan-khan)

And if you want to run it on **port 80**, you probably need to sudo.

Comment: is there anyway to set this as the default?

Comment: @twigg Not that I know of, unless you modify the source code itself. I guess you could write a custom command to wrap the serve command with your preferred arguments: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan

Comment: Yes. Its working for me `php artisan serve --port=8001`

Comment: Yes there is, as of Laravel 6: set `SERVER_PORT` in your .env file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823822/333340

Comment: @Synchro that's correct, I've updated the answer

Comment: This solution works for laravel v8 as well

Comment: SERVER_PORT, works but please dont forget to run cache:clean as this is read directly from env not from the cache.

Answer (score 48):

as this example you can change ip and port this works with me

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Comment: I'm running a test server on AWS / EC2. (instead of my local). So dropped this code into the terminal and I'm up and running!

Answer (score 15):

One can specify the port with: `php artisan serve --port=8080`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use many ports together for each project,

```
  php artisan serve --port=8000

  php artisan serve --port=8001   

  php artisan serve --port=8002

  php artisan serve --port=8003
```

Comment: I ran multiple laravel projects on different ports.It gives 404 not found error. Do I have to configure the port in somewhere else also.

Answer (score 6):

Andreas' answer above was helpful in solving my problem of how to test artisan on port 80. Port 80 can be specified like the other port numbers, but regular users do not have permissions to run anything on that port.

Drop a little common sense on there and you end up with this for Linux:

```
sudo php artisan serve --port=80
```

This will allow you to test on localhost without specifying the port in your browser. You can also use this to set up a temporary demo, as I have done.

**Keep in mind, however, that PHP's built in server is not designed for production. Use nginx/Apache for production.**

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
php artisan serve --port 80
```

Works on Windows platform

Answer (score 5):

you can also add host as well with same command like :

```
php artisan serve --host=172.10.29.100 --port=8080
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start
```

This fixed my issue AFTER ensuring my ports were all uniquely sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

when we use the

```
php artisan serve
```

it will start with the default HTTP-server port mostly it will be `8000` when we want to run the more site in the localhost we have to change the port. Just add the --port argument:

```
php artisan serve --port=8081
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel Framework 11.0.8

As mentioned in the `sail` file:
`./vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail`

```
# Open the site...
#...
#...
        if [[ -n "$APP_PORT" && "$APP_PORT" != "80" ]]; then
            FULL_URL="${APP_URL}:${APP_PORT}"
        else
            FULL_URL="$APP_URL"
        fi
#...
#...
```

1- Open the `.env` file and add the following code:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_PORT=8001
```

2- then run it :

```
./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
./vendor/bin/sail up -d // or ./vendor/bin/sail up
```