# How to change default url from localhost:8000 to other Ip in laravel when we run "php artisan serve"

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am running `php artisan serve` command

by default the result is :

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

I want to change pointing to other ip

Comment: SERVER_PORT to .env works, but dont forget to run cache:clean as this is read directly from env not cache.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1 --port 80
```

Answer (score 11):

```
# php artisan serve --help
Usage:
  serve [options]

Options:
      --host[=HOST]     The host address to serve the application on. [default: "127.0.0.1"]
      --port[=PORT]     The port to serve the application on. [default: 8000]
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Help:
  Serve the application on the PHP development server
```

Answer (score 11):

To change default host and/or port for the artisan serve command, you need to edit the ServeCommand.php file:

```
$ sudo nano vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php
```

At the end of it you will find were they are configured:

```
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on', '127.0.0.1'],
            ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on', '8000'],
        ];
    }
```

Just change de default value of the host 127.0.0.1 for the ip of your desired host. And 8000 for the number of your desired port.

My case:
I have an UbuntuServer 18.04 VM running over GoogleCloud - ComputeEngine, I was unable to see the Laravel execution until I changed the host to 0.0.0.0, of course I changed the port as well to have the 80 as default.

The alternative was executing every time:

```
$ sudo php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

in order to obtain the same result.

Comment: Note that whenever you update the framework, these changes are lost. It's better to override this class, such as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50640514/2286722).

Comment: Good to know @MartenKoetsier, for sure it seems a better solution not just a patch as i did!

Answer (score 10):

On Laravel 6 you can create a variable `SERVER_PORT` in your .env file

Example:

```
SERVER_PORT=80
```

Will produce:

```
$ php artisan serve
 Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @Macr1408 answer, since Laravel at this date does not offer a host name/ip config setting (like the SERVER_PORT one), you could extend the ServeCommand class and just redefine what parent getOptions method returns. Here is an example that allows you to set a SERVER_HOST env config value that will change your IP/host name when you run artisan serve:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand as LaraServe;

class ServeCommand extends LaraServe
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $options = parent::getOptions();
        $options[0][4] =  env('SERVER_HOST');

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are acceptable.
I am replying to the question "which file have to make changes". If you want to run `php artisan serve` without `--port={port_number}`, you can change the port number in `ServeCommand.php` under `port()` method.

[image]