# Set default 'host' value for `php artisan serve`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am building a Laravel site, and want to test it on other devices as I build it (phone, ipad etc).

As I understand it, the way to do this is to run `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`.

My question is... is there a way to define a default value for the host, and set it to 0.0.0.0, so that I can simply run `php artisan serve` and it will automatically run on `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: If you're working with Homestead, take a look at the `aliases` file. If you work on macOS or any other *NIX system, you can provide your own alias as usual. I don't know Windows, but there probably is a way to create an alias for this command too. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-homestead-aliases

Comment: Not working with Homestead here: a simple `php artisan serve` should be enough to get you going: "_Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>_"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do next thing:

1. `php artisan make:command CustomServeCommand`
2. Then delete all from file and use this code:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Console\Commands;

   use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand;
   use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

   class CustomServeCommand extends ServeCommand
   {
       /**
        * Get the console command options.
        *
        * @return array
        */
       protected function getOptions()
       {
           return [
               ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', '0.0.0.0'],//default 127.0.0.1
               ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 8000],
           ];
       }
   }
   ```
3. `php artisan serve`

[Link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php) to the core file.

Basically, you will extend default class and adapt method to fit your own needs. This way you can set host and port per requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Just for anyone else reading this, the new `CustomServeCommand` file is located in `app\Console\Commands\CustomServeCommand.php`. Replace the contents of _this_ file with the above, and it works great!

Comment: I got "The 'no-reload' option does not exist." error when I tried your solution

Comment: @MarioAriyanto Is possible `no-reload` belongs to some custom code and not to Laravel's default code? If so, it would be good to [write detailed question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) about issue. I am not sure if it is solvable through comments here.

Answer (score 0):

The getOptions is extended in version 10 it should be:

```
protected function getOptions()
{
    return [
        ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on', Env::get('SERVER_HOST', '0.0.0.0')],
        ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on', Env::get('SERVER_PORT')],
        ['tries', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The max number of ports to attempt to serve from', 10],
        ['no-reload', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Do not reload the development server on .env file changes'],
    ];
}
```

The code seems to read the .env settings, but the data is not available here (to early in the process?).