# I can not connect laravel as django is already in my pc

Tags: php, django, laravel

I installed Django on my PC, but I want to install Laravel also. But my localhost didn't connect. Whenever I want to connect to Laravel in localhost it gives an error like

> "Laravel development server started:
>   [Thu Oct  5 01:41:01 2017] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

How can I fix it?

Comment: see here to figure out how to check what processes are using port 8000 https://superuser.com/questions/977445/how-do-i-find-out-what-services-are-bound-to-a-port-number

Comment: Are you using `artisan serve`? You can set the port with that command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990820/set-port-for-php-artisan-php-serve

Comment: it worked.thank u so much