# using symfony and laravel together : local server Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, webserver

I'am using Symfony and Laravel on same machine.
I'am on developement, and I have no webserver, I use the local server of each of them.

For Symfony, that works :

```
$ cd /var/www/symfony
$ php bin/console server:start

 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

For Laravel, that does not work :

```
$ cd /var/www/laravel
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Thu Oct 12 21:46:21 2017] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000
```

When I stop the Symfony, then the Laravel works. There is a conflict between the 2 tools.

I am obliged to have the 2 working, because there is a REST-API on my Lavavel site and my symfony site is a client of this API.

How can I run the 2 sites with local development server, without installing a webserver ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990820/set-port-for-php-artisan-php-serve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set port for php artisan.php serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990820/set-port-for-php-artisan-php-serve)

Comment: You can't run both on the same port. Change one of them e.g. `php artisan serve --port=8080`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you can not share the same port on the same host.

I don't know Laravel, but I know Symfony. With Symfony you can change the port of the local server with this command :

```
php bin/console server:stop
php bin/console server:start 127.0.0.1:8080
```

After this command, you can try to restart your Laravel server, and you will have :

- Symfony on url http://127.0.0.1:8080
- Laravel on url http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0):

Use below command for run laravel project.

`php artisan serve --port=8888`

Using this command you can run laravel project in a different port.