# Should I rely on "php artisan serve" for a locally based project?

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a project with Laravel that will be run (and used) on a local machine. Is it advisable to simply run it with "php artisan serve" or should I install a server for it? Does this command have any impact on the app's performance?

And if I can rely on that command for launching the application, can I change the port on which it runs or will it always be 8000? Can I customize it so that the app will only be accessible from `localhost`?

**Edit:** The intended version for the project is 5.3

Comment: You can run localhost on another port https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990820/set-port-for-php-artisan-php-serve.
If you use mac, you can install valet then park catalog domain and use name of catalog at domain example your-project.loc. For other system you can use homstead. Check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8.

Comment: You can use php artisan serve --port=8888 to run in different port.

Comment: `serve` is only accesible locally by default

Comment: You should use Laravel/Homestead instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this command have any impact on the app's performance?

Yes. `php artisan serve` uses [PHP's built-in dev webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which states:

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

If your app makes multiple simultaneous requests (like an image gallery, or multiple CSS + JS files on your page), or multiple users are accessing it concurrently, or if any of your requests are particularly *slow* to process (like making external cURL calls), it will be slow as the requests will be handled one-by-one sequentially.

Running it on [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) or [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet) will be more performant.