# Very slow response if there is an error in laravel view or component

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, view

I'm new to laravel and I'm building a pure laravel 9 app(no vue, nodejs or other frameworks just laravel + vanilla js). If I have any kind of error in any laravel view/component/partials the error page response tooks more then 20seconds to appears. If I have an error in any controller/model/config or other laravel's environment files, the same error is superfast. In example if I have a typo in my view layout.blade.php

**PHP**

```
@php
ech 'missing a letter';
@endphp
```

this will throw the error in 20 seconds

if I place a typo in a controller like this

**PHP**

```
public function index() {
    retur 'missing a letter';
}
```

this will throw the error instantly.

if this can helps, checking in my console the laravel log file like this

**DEBIAN BASH**

```
tail -f /var/www/mylaravelapp/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

will throw the error in the same time that appears in the laravel error page.
Obviuously is not a big deal, but since I'm working on the appareance of the UI, this will slow down my work so much.

**UPDATE**

I'm adding a screen of my devtools opened, it simply waits for server response 23 seconds
[image]

**UPDATE**

Some new details, really strange for me, what happens is that in my component I have some pure javascript script in the bottom of the page(around 500 rows). If I delete the scripts the error page will run superfast. I tried to place the scripts directly behind the scripts tags and I tried using the @pushOnce directive with same results. I tried to reduce the amount of code, and the more I reduce the code the more will run faster. I tried to put the script directly in my layout.blade.php that calls the component and it runs superfast, I tried to put the js code like an external script and it runs superfat, **so problem happens only with inline JS** probably I'm placing the scripts in a wrong way

**UPDATE**

OK I think this update is important, if I run my laravel app through my apache web server(so not using php artisan) the error page will load superfast, so this cannot be related to some code error. Usually I run my laravel app in this way

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.25.209
```

where 192.168.25.209 is a server in my network that is hosting my laravel app. As @Don't Panic pointed in the comments

```
"The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked"
```

So I checked for permissions on cache storage folders, but everything looks good, cache files and logs are correctly written

Comment: How fast is view returned when you don't have an error?

Comment: superfast around 100ms without any caching envrionment and e couple of libraries loaded (font awesome and axios )

Comment: Not a solution but for text output in blade files you should use `{{ $variable }}`

Comment: is the same, I just reported the echo example for making things easier

Comment: Try using something like `info('test')` in your controller. Is it fast or slow? If slow then problem could be related to file writing

Comment: Does browser devtools show any clues, eg are there some remote resources timing out on the error page or something like that? Are your files on a network drive, or mounted somehow unusually, anything like that?  Anything special about the `storage/` dir (where logs and caches etc are written)?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 is superfast! only errors are slow.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I added a screen of my devtools, I'm serving with php artisan serve ther is no cache environment, the files are on a virtual machine in my network with host 192.168.25.209. The files can be written very fast, because the problem happens only with views, if I have an error in the controller is superfast.

Comment: Not sure what "*the files are on a virtual machine in my network*" means exactly, but that sounds like a big red flag to me, at least something to test. Try hosting files locally, see if the problem persists.

Comment: can you clear `view cache` and test the time taken for the page load when there is no error. `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @Don'tPanic simply I have phisical servers in my company, one of those servers is a vmware host, on this host there is dedicate debian VM that I can access through my local network. On this VM there is my laravel App. How can this be a red flag for you? How can you deploy webapps if you work only on your local machine? Everything works superfast except the errors in views. For me it looks like a giant loop somewhere in my app.

Comment: @iamab.in I did it and it tooks around 250ms(including font awesome and axios cdn)

Comment: :-) "*the files are on a virtual machine*" makes it sound like files are not on the same machine as the web server, a sure way to see strange performance issues.

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry maybe I didn't explain myself well, I meant the whole development environment (LAMP server + laravel files)

Comment: I added an update regarding how javascript impacts the error page performance

Comment: You mentioned "*ther is no cache environment*" - Laravel has caching bulit in, you can see the config in `config/cache.php`.  If you haven't touched it, by default it will be using file caching, and reading/writing to files on disk under `storage/framework/`.  Do you see (current) files in there? There are many examples here on SO of mis-configured cache, or other cache-related problems causing slow performance. Might be worth investigating, if you haven't already.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I cleared the cache already as you suggested, and investigated cache problems bu I think this update is important, if I run my laravel app through my apache web server(so not using php artisan) the error page will load superfast, so this cannot be related to some code error or laravel misconfiguration. Usually I run my laravel app in this way `php artisan serve --host 192.168.25.209` where 192.168.25.209 is the server in my network that is hosting my laravel app

Comment: I didn't suggest clearing cache, I wondered if there is a problem reading/writing to the cache files on disk (or whatever cache you have configured).  Checking [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) about the built in server, they say: "*The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked*".  So maybe that's the only problem, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946340/should-i-rely-on-php-artisan-serve-for-a-locally-based-project

Comment: @Don'tPanic I can clearly see the creation of cache files under folder /var/www/html/disponibilita/storage/framework/cache and /var/www/html/disponibilita/storage/framework/views in both artisan and apache environment. I really cannot figure out what is happening.